# Sockets with Android Client an PC Server

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

I've seen a few of these questions around, but none of the answers seem to resolve my problem.
I want to display a message on my server (PC) from my client (Android phone, I actually have a physical **device**).
I have an extremely simple PC server:

```
public void run(int port) throws Exception
{
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket sock = ss.accept();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
}
```

(In my main void):

```
Server s = new Server();
s.run(4444);
```

And an extremely simple Android client:

```
package com.j03.client;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            runClient("10.0.2.2", 4444, "hey");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TextView t = new TextView(this);
            t.setText(e.getMessage());
            setContentView(t);
        }
    }

    public static void runClient(String ip, int port, String message) throws Exception
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(ip, port);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(message);
    }
}
```

I also have the proper internet permissions in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And the client code works fine as a PC Client. (PC Client to PC Server works fine).

but I can not get it to work on Android!

The PC server simply displays nothing. :(

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You are only setting the TextView when there is an exception.  If everything works properly then you never display anything on the screen.

Comment: When 'runClient()' is called it is supposed to send the message to the server. The exception is showing any errors (Which it did before I added the correct permissions to my manifest).
The client isn't supposed to display any text.

Comment: So, then what exactly isn't working?  It sounded like the problem was "I simply get a blank screen. "

Comment: Yea sorry about that, I realized I wasn't very clear with my question.
I am trying to send a message from the client to the server. Nothing is showing up on the server side.

Comment: Try doing this with threads, as shown [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/). As already stated, the OS (Android) might be thinking that the UI is not responding and terminating your application.

Comment: I will try that thank you. But my android app never force closes.

Comment: Since you are using 10.0.2.2, I assume you are running this on the emulator.  Have you tried using an actual device?  Maybe a firewall or some other setting is preventing the emulator from sending packets to your localhost.

Comment: Oh, I actually am on a device. I also tried "localhost", but that did not work also.

Answer (score 0):

You also might be doing this all on the UI thread. I think android sometimes will kill your app if you do this and display Application is not responding dialogs.

The other poster is also correct about your Activity being empty until an exception occurs. I would fix that and try starting a separate thread with your runClient in it

Comment: I will try that thank you. But my android app never force closes.